# Chevron right in button won't show on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a button with a chevron right icon in it, this is actually a png as I wanted to eliminate the request for ionicons (or similar) font.

To display well at mobile sizes (and not make the button drop over 2 lines) I have decreased the size of the chevron by changing it's width down to 10px as scale was not working.

For desktop my button displays perfectly down to 315px which is ideal. On tablets it displays as it should. But for some reason on actual mobile devices the chevron refuses to display.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk/promotions/fifty-pounds-cashback.htm" class="apply">Find out more<img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mysite/v2-remake/glyphicons-224-chevron-right.png" class="chevronr" alt="Find_out_more"></a>
```

Mobile CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 491px) {
  #rmOv_cp_v1 .chevronr {
    width: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on your layout you the chevron may be outside of the screen display, which might be due to its padding.

Comment: Could you recreate the problem [here](http://codepen.io/pen/)?